# Is my Regex/htaccess syntax correct?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I finally decided to delve into the wonderful world of Regular Expressions.

Basically my aim is to

**Browser sends**:

```
http://example.com/search/Bombay
```

**Apache translates into this**:

```
http://example.com/search/?city=Bombay
```

My rule attempt is this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/?$ search/?city=$1
```

Would this be the correct way to do this? Is there any good places to learn more about Regex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested your current pattern? It should work fine. Be sure to enable mod_rewrite: `RewriteEngine on` and `Options +FollowSymLinks`.

Comment: And don' forge to add `[L,QSA]` flags in the end like this: `RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]+)/?$ search/?city=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/),  [Apache Mod_Rewrite Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match too much in that regex. I would go for

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ search/?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also notice that I have added the `NC` non-case-sensitive flag and the `L` last flag this means if a user types in the URL in mixed or upper case then it will still match also once it matches it will stop accessing the htaccess file and go with what you have currently matched.

Try to learn about them here http://www.regular-expressions.info/ or get a decent book.

Also really you should try these things before posting here.